# Spring amqp cachingConnectionFactory not shutting down for a minute

Tags: spring-amqp

My client application is a Spring-shell application, running SpringBoot 2.1.1.

We are creating rabbitmq connection on demand `CachingConnectionFacotry`

```
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(uri);

    connectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
```

When exiting the application, calling `cachingConnectionFactory.destroy();` on @PreDestroy and/or `onContextClosed` events is not shutting down `cachingConnectionFactory` .
It is taking a minute for the application to exit.

Thread dump below indicates there is an executor inside `cachingConnectionFactory` that hasnt shutdown yet.

```html
"spring-rabbit-deferred-pool-12" #29 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff61245e000 nid=0x7503 waiting on condition [0x000070000fa57000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
 at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 - parking to wait for  <0x000000076c928300> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
 at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
 at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"spring-rabbit-deferred-pool-11" #28 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff616461000 nid=0x7303 waiting on condition [0x000070000f954000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
 at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 - parking to wait for  <0x000000076c928300> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
 at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
 at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"process reaper" #14 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff614cd0800 nid=0x590b waiting on condition [0x000070000ec2d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
 at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c078c1e0> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
 at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
 at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Anything I can do to exit the application immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's related to that thread pool...

```
public final void destroy() {
    super.destroy();
    resetConnection();
    if (getContextStopped()) {
        this.stopped = true;
        if (this.channelsExecutor != null) {
            this.channelsExecutor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

`shutDownNow()` is called after resetting the connection and, clearly, all of the threads are interruptible.

Best guess is something (perhaps network related) is delaying the `resetConnection()`.

Post the **complete** thread dump while the delay is enountered, perhaps in a GitHub gist, or on pastebin, or similar.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking into this. Only thing we changed is upgraded to Springboot 2.1.1 from 2.1.0

Comment: Why are you calling `destroy()` yourself? If the connection factory is declared as a Spring Bean, the application context will destroy it for you. As you can see, there is conditional logic in `destroy()` to only terminate the executor if it has, itself, received a context closed event. If the factory is a bean, this should all be automatic; and there is no need to call destroy from application code.

Comment: In our CLI, Connection to rabbitmq is on demand.  CLI is able to connect to any broker and discover services. So CachingConnectionFactory is not a bean.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it's not a `Bean`. Regardless, when it's not a bean, you are responsible for satisfying all the contracts it expects. `InitializingBean, BeanNameAware, DisposableBean, 
ApplicationContextAware, ApplicationEventPublisherAware, ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>`. So, propagating the `ContextClosedEvent` should solve your issue. But; it would be better to let the framework take care of it for you.

Comment: Registering CachingConnectionFactory as a bean solved the issues. Thanks!!

Comment: When `CachingConnectionFactory` is configured as a bean, application exits immediately but prints out the following on termination. I cannot tell if it is indicative of something bad.. https://gist.github.com/vavrfam/48826d2b04691b46d9e3b0b28aa586bb

Comment: It can be ignored, but we should suppress those log messages; please open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).