# SpringBoot application stopped about 1 minute if exception occurred on starting

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp

I have spring boot application that starts like this:`

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

and there is component RabbitHandlers on the creation of which I get error:

```
Component
public class RabbitHandlers {

    public RabbitHandlers(@Qualifier("rmq") CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {

        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(initProducerConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory));

        try {
            checkExchangeDeclared(rabbitTemplate, rabbitConfigHandler.getOutput().getExchange());
        } catch (RabbitException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
            rabbitTemplate.stop();
            //this.consumerConnectionFactory.destroy();
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private static void checkExchangeDeclared(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate, String exchange) {
        AMQP.Exchange.DeclareOk execute = rabbitTemplate.execute(channel -> {
            try {
                return channel.exchangeDeclarePassive(exchange);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.error("Exchange {} error: {}", exchange, ex.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        });
        if (execute == null) {
            throw new RabbitException(String.format("Exchange '%s' doesn't exist in vhost='%s'",
                    exchange,
                    rabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getVirtualHost()));
        }
    }

    private CachingConnectionFactory initProducerConnectionFactory(CachingConnectionFactory consumerConnectionFactory) {
        // В CachingConnectionFactory фабрика коннектов есть всегда, но на всякий случай проверим.
        if (!consumerConnectionFactory.hasPublisherConnectionFactory()) {
            throw new RabbitException("ConnectionFactory for publisher is null");
        }

        return (CachingConnectionFactory) consumerConnectionFactory.getPublisherConnectionFactory();
    }
}
```

My code creates CachingConnectionFactory:

```
    @Bean("rmq")
    @Scope("prototype")
    CachingConnectionFactory getCachingConnectionFactory() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory();
    }
```

In my case exception occured that leads to spring app stopped with error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2023.01.18 01:06:17.284] [ERROR] [main] [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure() at line 843]<-----><------>Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitHandlers' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/alpha_tech_user/workspa
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:315)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:296)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
<------>at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
<------>at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
<------>at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
<------>at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
<------>at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
<------>at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
<------>at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
<------>at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
<------>at com.application.Application.main(Application.java:16)
<------>at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
<------>at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
<------>at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
<------>at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
<------>at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
<------>at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
<------>at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
<------>at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.application.rabbitmq.RabbitHandlers]: Constructor threw exception;
<------>at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311)
<------>... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.application.exceptions.RabbitException: Exchange 'output' doesn't exist in vhost='vhost'
<------>at com.application.rabbitmq.RabbitHandlers.checkExchangeDeclared(RabbitHandlers.java:112)
<------>at com.application.rabbitmq.RabbitHandlers.<init>(RabbitHandlers.java:32)
<------>at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
<------>at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
<------>at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
<------>at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
<------>at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
<------>... 29 common frames omitted
```

The problem is that application doesn't stop immediately but only after 1 minute.
As I've understood, the problem is that then application context stopped it have to close
CachingConnectionFactory, but something is going wrong (

P.S. I think that problem is related to [Spring Boot onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) not called on in case of exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71353986/spring-boot-onapplicationeventcontextclosedevent-event-not-called-on-in-case-o)
But how to execute context.close() in my case?

Comment: You need to provide much more context, including the full stack trace, the `rabbitHandlers` definition and exactly where you are using the template. Edit the question; don't try to put that stuff in comments. You must not use the connection before the application context is initialized.

Comment: @GaryRussell,  I've add needed info

Answer (score 0):

```
checkExchangeDeclared(rabbitTemplate, rabbitConfigHandler.getOutput().getExchange());
```

You should not be doing this in the constructor.

Change `RabbitHandlers` to implement `SmartLifecycle` and check the exchange in the `start()` method instead.

Also

The problem is the prototype scope on the connection factory; prototype beans are not destroyed when the application context is closed. Add `cachingConnectionFactory.destroy();` to the catch block.

Comment: That said, I just copied your code into a new Boot app and it terminates immediately. Try taking a thread dump during the hang to see what the `main` thread is doing.

Comment: The problem take place than really amqp method was executed (if you get exception early, application stopped immediately).
When problem take place in thread dump there is spring-rabbit-deferred-pool thread/

Comment: Problem is corresponding to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788729/spring-amqp-cachingconnectionfactory-not-shutting-down-for-a-minute. but it doesn't work for me

Comment: The problem is the prototype scope on the connection factory; prototype beans are not destroyed when the application context is closed. Add `cachingConnectionFactory.destroy();` to the catch block. I would still recommend refactoring to move that code out of the constructor. Why do you need prototype scope there anyway?

Comment: Firstly I created cachingConnectionFactory with new() and exec destroy() method. 
As you watch this method there is a code 
if (getContextStopped()) { ...   this.channelsExecutor.shutdown(); ...}. In that case getContextStopped always return false and as result channelsExecutor.shutdown method was not executed. After that I found branch there man said that spring can manage it if factory will be Bean. As I need many factories I had to use prototype

Comment: I added `cachingConnectionFactory.destroy();` like I said, and it terminates immediately again (even with the prototype bean).

Comment: Now I have fixed it by adding
            this.consumerConnectionFactory.onApplicationEvent(new ContextClosedEvent(applicationContext));
            this.consumerConnectionFactory.destroy();
but it seems like a hack

Comment: As I said; it is not necessary to wait for the event; just destroy the factory, or use a singleton instead of a prototype.